# Why does `DagRun.find` return objects with None attributes

Tags: airflow

I am running airflow jobs using data-aware scheduling. A job that depends on updated datasets needs to find both the earliest and latest timestamps for the dags that initiated things.

All this data is easy accessible:

1. Get the `triggering_dataset_events`
2. Find the `run_id`'s of the jobs that triggered things.
3. Use `DagRun.find` to get the `DagRun` object of the triggering Dag
4. Get both the start and end timestamp.

I do it like this:

```
        @task()
        def get_start_and_end_timestamp(ti=None):
            template_context = ti.get_template_context()
            triggering_ds = template_context["triggering_dataset_events"]

            times = (
                seq(list(triggering_ds.values()))
                .flatten()  # Needs to be flattened because the form is [[ds_event1,...]]
                .map(lambda ds_event: ds_event.source_run_id)
                .map(lambda source_run_id: DagRun.find(run_id=source_run_id))
                .flatten()  # Needs to be flattened because DagRun.find returns a list of dags
                .filter(
                    lambda dag_run: dag_run is not None
                    and dag_run.start_date is not None
                    and dag_run.end_date is not None
                )
                .map(
                    lambda dag_run: (
                        dag_run.start_date.timestamp(),
                        dag_run.end_date.timestamp(),
                    )
                )
                .reduce(
                    lambda x, y: (min(x[0], y[0]), max(x[1], y[1])),
                    (sys.float_info.max, sys.float_info.min),
                )
            )

            # Assert everything is okay
            assert times[0] != sys.float_info.max, "times[0] == sys.float_info.max"
            assert times[1] != sys.float_info.min, "times[1] == sys.float_info.min"

            # Since timestamp() returns a float representing microseconds, multiply by 1e6 to get
            # an integer number
            return (int(times[0] * 1e6), int(times[1] * 1e6))
```

The question is that `DagRun.find` is returning objects that have None attributes which is forcing me to use the filter in the above code:

```
              .filter(
                    lambda dag_run: dag_run is not None
                    and dag_run.start_date is not None
                    and dag_run.end_date is not None
                )
```

The question: Why does airflow's `DagRun.find` do this, and what is being returned. With the filter, things seem to be working, but I don't know why this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a data integrity problem. I suspect that the task is being executed before the metadata has been loaded (or replicated). If this is the case, the way to fix things is just to retry with an exponential backoff. If that works, I will mark this question as answered.